# Remount /system rw

Tags: root-access, 4.3-jelly-bean, mount, partitions

i'm new here, so i apologize in advance if this is a n00bish question:

how could one remount /system (or any partition, for that matter) in rw and allow suid on a booted system via ADB wifi? here's some particulars:

- hardware=custom, no exterior ports
- bootloader=unknown
- kernel=loop device and module enabled
- ro.secure=1
- recovery=OEM
- version=4.3
- root=temp
- busybox=yes, custom
- mount=ext4; ro; relatime; barrier=1; nosuid

thnx

Comment: just fyi, i don't have microUSB access. i have to do this via wifi on a fully booted system.

Answer (score 1):

Once your debug bridge is connected, get it running as root with `adb root`. Then remount the partition read/write using `adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system`.

Not sure what you mean by the `suid` part of your question, but if you can elaborate, I will try to answer that as well.

Comment: i suppose the suid portion might be redundant, so nvm that. i have tried that one, no luck with it.

Comment: Are you getting an error on either or both of the 'adb' commands? If you are remounting rw and still unable to modify the partition, you may have a bios protection. Some phones, like HTC call this S-ON. This must be changed to S-OFF before the 'mount' command will do anything. It can be difficult to get S-OFF, depending on the model of phone.

Comment: adb root returns no error and build.prop shows adb running as root. i get the error when I pass the mount cmd to the shell.

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try running everything from the ADB shell.

`adb shell` 
`su`
`mount -o remount,rw /system`

If you install something as root "su" you can use `chown` to change the owner of the file.  It's not quite like using suid but at least you can change the owner.

It also looks likes Busybox has suid built in, if you have the right version.

Check out [this website](http://www.softforge.de/bb/suid.html) for more info.

Comment: tried from the shell and from term emu installed via [adb install]. I have an su binary in /sdcard/Download, as well as one in /data/local, but can't execute the one in /sdcard. i'll try [chown] on the /sdcard/Download binary. thnx for the link. updates to come.

Comment: What error are you getting when trying to execute the binary under /sdcard?  You might need to change the permissions `chmod 6774 su` of the binary.

Comment: "system/bin/sh: ./su: can't execute: Permission denied"

Comment: And your tablet is rooted, correct?

Comment: temp root from a binary pushed to /data/local/ and executed.

Comment: Then try running `/data/loca/temp_root <root command to execute>`  to run it as root and you shouldn't get a permission denied error. where temp_ root is the name of your root program and <root command to execute> is the command to be executed as root.  I've never heard of a temp root before though..

Comment: ok. i haven't tried it that way yet. i'll give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: temp rooting is when you push an su binary thru adb to a directory you can execute from. in my case, /data/local. the root shell is temporary because it doesn't survive reboot.

Comment: @D.Gibbs Isn't it `/data/local/temp_root -c <command>`? Oh, and the `su` binary is given `06755` permissions in some Android ROMs, so there's that.

Comment: @aureljared, thanks for the permissions.  The command might have `-c` on some ROM's but I don't remember using it.  But that's not to say that I'm mistaken :)  @particlewave_delta: why not just root the tablet permanently?