# Chrome app returns after restart

Tags: uninstallation, system-apps

I have a rooted OnePlus 5t, I'm trying to remove the Chrome app (same problem with Google Duo), using a system app remover, or through Total Commander delete it from its folder. As soon as I do that the app stops working, and after rebooting it always goes back to the folder: `system \ product \ app \ Chrome \ Chrome.apk`

If I'm typing in adb: `pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.chrome` and delete the Chrome.apk with Total Commander - the app is removed from my device even after reboot! but the installation apk still coming back after the reboot!!!!
When I'm installing the app from the Chrome.apk the apk path know is: `\data\app\com.android.chorme-zqnclvqlfjlosvpkkista==\base.apk`

I googled and found no answer

Comment: `/system` is the system partition which is read-only. If you uninstall an app the apk on the system partition will always stay instead the app is just disabled.

Comment: I root my device for a reason... Is there any way to delete it permanently? I am a SU...

Comment: Even on rooted devices the system partition is read-only, however with root permissions you can remount the partition read/write. Please be aware that removing web browser/WebView providing app may end up in a non-booting device.

Comment: `however with root permissions you can remount the partition read/write` How can I do that? can you help me?

Comment: You can simply search this site for `system` `remount` and end up e.g. here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109655/remount-system-rw

Comment: WOW ty! I'm trying that right know... I saw solution with adb, is there a way to do it with the TWRP?

Comment: The TWRP versions I know have a button for remounting system partition.

Comment: WOW! its worked!!!!!! ty !!! I found this command: `mount -o rw,remount /`. The chrome is gone! and even the apk is gone from: `system \ product \ app \ Chrome \ Chrome.apk`